# Joomla Contact Component - add custom fields

Tags: joomla-3.x

I need to add  latitude and longitude to Contact Component.
In **administrator\components\com_contact\contact.xml** I added this two lines.

```
<field name="latitude" type="text"size="30"/>          
<field name="longitude" type="text"size="30"/>
```

**administrator\templates\isis\html\com_contact\contact**

```
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('latitude'); ?>
<?php echo $this->form->renderField('longitude'); ?>
```

When I save the form with values, the values are not saved?

Comment: Ha ha. Perhaps for the same GMaps plugin as I use.

Answer (score 1):

You need also add columns to table in DB

and may be you'll need to add code that will accept you field values and store then.

Answer (score 1):

The first problem is the path, you need override the component from: **your_site/components/com_contact**
not **your_site/administrator/components/com_contact**

Also the code for the template must be in: **your_site/templates/your_template**

Here you have an example: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20586581/adding-fields-to-joomla-3-x-contact-component

Other possible solution is via plugin, find more info here:
https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_core_components_using_a_plugin